# I'm receiving a fatal error when compiling my first C++ program, "No such file or directory" when running the task

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors

I'm  following a tutorial via YouTube from freecodecamp on learning C++. I've followed each step carefully and even rewatched the first few steps in order to retain what I've learned. After downloading the compiler and making sure the arguments are in place, I'm still receiving a fatal error message. I'm still not sure of the basic steps and I've been stuck for a couple hours trying to figure it out on my own. I understand that the compiler is simply translating the code I've written into a form that the computer itself can read.

The code;

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    auto result = (10 <=> 20) > 0;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The "tasks.json";

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Build with GCC 13.2.0",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
        "-std=c++20",
        "${workspacefolder}\\*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\Llama.exe",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc",
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        }
    ]
}
```

When running the task I get a fatal error of "No such file or directory".

I changed the label to building with GCC 13.2.0 because that is the version i downloaded. And that helped my first issue. But it brought about the "fatal error" message after the change. I was expecting the build to finish appropriately, however that's clearly not the case.
I feel like it could be the version that's incorrect but something tells me i just simply need to add a folder of the name "Llama.exe", I'm running a 64-bit rig and have downloaded the G++/GCC MinGW-w64 WITH Clang from WinLibs.

I'm sorry if I'm speaking in circles, I come from a Horticulturist's background so please speak as if I'm a child. I plan on this being my future and i want to build a solid foundation for my journey.

Comment: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe - such path is a clear sign that you haven't followed the official vscode guide of installing g++. Please explain, what guide you have followed and why not [the official one](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_example-install-mingwx64-on-windows).

Comment: In other words "I'm a very new beginner"

Comment: thanks for your slander but i figured out that I clearly just didn't add the right c++ support... It should have been "-std=c++23" rather than "-std=c++20" I appreciate your time, but you didn't help much but add a bit more discouragement to my mental library. Regardless, I'm glad you opened my eyes to needing more knowledge on why it may better to develop on a Linux OS rather than Windows, not sure why, But I'll take your criticism into account for what it's worth...